# Call of Duty Black Ops 2 Final Killcams

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How does the game determine who gets the final killcams?

Sometimes I get the last kill, but someone else gets their killcam previewed

Answer (score 2):

Were you on the winning team? Typically Call of Duty shows the final kill of the winning team as the final killcam.

From the wiki:

> In Call of Duty: Black Ops II, the Final Killcam is similar to Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3, where it shows the last kill by the winning team in any match/round.